# How do I hide the title when creating/editing a specific type of content?

Tags: nodes

Here's what we'd like to do when create/edit node of specific type of content (we have 2 specific types, let's call them "type A" and "type B"):

- hide the title (= the user can change all fields but *not the title*)
- show a combo box to choose an item (lot of items, and this field is a long name)
- depending on the **type** of the content, when validating the node, update the title like this: `title = name of the item + " - " + type of the content`

Example:

User creates a node of "type B". He chooses the item called "The item XYZ long name" and validates `=>` the title of the node is auto-magically created: `The item XYZ long name - Type B`.

Any idea how to do this (I don't know how to hide the title when creating/editing a node as well)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great module you can use is [Auto NodeTitle](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) :

> "auto_nodetitle" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of
>   the content title field in the form. To prevent empty content title
>   fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.
>
> When the token module is installed it's possible to use various node
>   data for the auto generated title - e.g. use the text of a CCK field
>   (since 5.x).
>
> Advanced users can also provide some PHP code, that is used for
>   automatically generating an appropriate title.